# Angular 2 - Subscribing issue, not displaying output

Tags: angular, routes, subscribe

I'm currently trying to get by configure my api for a web-app i'm building and I have a button driven menu that pulls data from the api and is supposed to change all of the data and charts displayed on the web page based on what data source you click on in the menu.

The Issue i'm having comes from getting lost in subscriptions and maybe some incorrect syntax, Causing data not to be displayed in my output. I'm still learning and would appreciate any tips!

**sprint.ts**

```
export class ISprint {
    Id: string;
    Name: string;
    Number: number;
}
```

**Summary.ts**

```
export class ISummary {
  SprintName: string;
  HoursCommitted: number;
  HoursToDo: number;
  PointsCommitted: number;
  PointsCompletd: number;
  WorkHoursRemaining: number;
  MemberDetails: IMemberDetails[];
}

export class IMemberDetails {
  Name: string;
  HoursCommitted: number;
  HoursToDo: number;
  PointsCommitted: number;
  PointsCompleted: number;
  ItemsWithoutPoints: number;
  ItemCount: number;  
}
```

**Sprint.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class SprintService {
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {

  }

  //  --- SPRINT CLASS from Sprint.ts
//   export class ISprint {
//     SprintID: number;
//     SprintName: string;
//     SpringNumber: number;
// }



  getSprintsWeb(): Observable<ISprint[]> {
    var data = this._http.get<ISprint[]>("http://localhost:52692/api/sprint");
    return data;
  }

  public getSprintWeb(TimeBox : string): Observable<ISummary> {
    // debugger;
    console.log("blahhhhhh");
    var url = "http://localhost:52692/api/sprint?TimeBox=" + TimeBox;
    return this._http.get<ISummary>(url);
  }
}
```

**Header.Component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'app';
  private apiURL = 'http://localhost:52692/api/sprint';
  error: string;
  summary: ISummary;
  sprints: ISprint[];
  newdate: string;

  constructor(private _summaryService: SummaryService, private _sprintService: SprintService ) {
    this.summary = new ISummary(); 
    this.sprints = new Array<ISprint>();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    //this.summary = this._summaryService.getSummary();

    this._summaryService.getSummaryWeb()
    .subscribe(summary => { this.summary = summary },
      error => this.error = <any>error);


      this._sprintService.getSprintsWeb()
      .subscribe((sprints) => {
        this.sprints = sprints;
        console.log(this.sprints)
      }, error => this.error = <any>error);


        const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
        "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
        var dateObj = new Date();
        var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
        var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
        var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();
        const d = new Date();
        this.newdate = monthNames[d.getMonth()] + " " + day + "," + " " + year;
      }

      dataUpdate( item: ISprint) {
        console.log(item);

        this._sprintService.getSprintWeb(item.Id)
        .subscribe((summary) => {
          this.summary = summary;
        }, error => this.error = <any>error);

        this.summary.SprintName = item.Name;
        console.log(this.summary);
      }
}
```

**Header.component.Html**

```
<mat-card style="background: #141d26; ">
    <!-- Left Header -->
    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
      <mat-icon style="font-size: 40px; color: white">list</mat-icon> 
    </button> 

    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu" >
      <a style="float: left" *ngFor = "let item of sprint;" routerLink = "/Summary" routerLinkActive = "active">
          <button  (click)="dataUpdate(item)" mat-menu-item style="border-inline-end-color: #141d26; border-width: 1mm"> {{item.Name}}</button>
      </a>
    </mat-menu>

    <!-- <router-outlet></router-outlet> -->

    <!-- Center -->
        <button mat-button style="font-family: 'Megrim', cursive; color: white; height:32px; font-size: 42px; font-weight: bolder;" > CSC  Sprint-alYtics</button>
        <mat-icon style="font-size: 40px; color: white">directions_run</mat-icon> 

    <!-- Right -->
    <h1 style="float: right; font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif; color: white"> {{newdate}} </h1>
</mat-card>
```

Thanks!

Comment: it is not *ngFor = "let item of sprints ? see the final "s". Andbe carefull,  when you write  this.summary.SprintName = item.Name; is outside of subscribe

Comment: Did you sseen any error in console? And also you are looping sprint variable not sprints so wrong please change.

Comment: Show your console log. And also note this line printed or not console.log(this.sprints)